# Windows Phone MenyFlyout crash

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have two app bar buttons in my Windows Phone app. Let's call them Button1 and Button2. Each button shows a `MenuFlyout` with some items. The problem is very simple. When tapping Button1, the corresponding `MenuFlyout` appears. If tapping Button2 while de `MenuFlyout` from Button1 is open the app crashes with a "Critical failure" exception. If a `MenuFlyout` is open and I tap outside of it and then press the button for the other `MenuFlyout` it works. I tried to hide one of the `MenuFlyouts` from code when tapping the button for the other one but is still crashes. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any code you can share to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the first button:

```
    private void SelectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (menuFlyout != null)
        {
            menuFlyout.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < listSource.View.Count; i++)
            {
                flyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
                flyoutItem.Text = this.listSource.View[i].ToString();
                flyoutItem.FontSize = 16;
                flyoutItem.FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                flyoutItem.Click += flyoutItem_Click;
                menuFlyout.Items.Add(flyoutItem);
            }
            menuFlyout.ShowAt(CmdBar);
        }
    }
```

and here is the other button:

```
    private void FilterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (filterFlyout != null)
        {
            filterFlyout.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < _filterList.Count; i++)
            {
                FilterItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
                FilterItem.Text = _filterList[i];
                FilterItem.FontSize = 16;
                FilterItem.FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                FilterItem.Click += FilterItem_Click;
                filterFlyout.Items.Add(FilterItem);
            }
            filterFlyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem());
            filterFlyout.ShowAt(CmdBar);
        }
    }
```

and here is the xaml for the buttons:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="CmdBar" Background="#F0A30A" Foreground="Black">
        <AppBarButton x:Uid="SelectButton" x:Name="SelectButton" Icon="Calendar" Label="day filter" Click="SelectButton_Click">
           <AppBarButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="menuFlyout">
                <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                    </Style>
                </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="flyoutItem" Background="Black" Click="flyoutItem_Click" Margin="0,0,20.833,0"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton x:Uid="FilterButton" x:Name="FilterButton" Icon="Clock" Label="time filter" Click="FilterButton_Click">
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="filterFlyout">
                <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                    </Style>
                </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="FilterItem" Click="FilterItem_Click" Margin="0,0,20.833,0"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```